Error after updating Solana program to 1.18.17 and Anchor to 0.30.1
I recently updated my Solana program to version 1.18.17 and Anchor to version 0.30.1. After the update, I am encountering errors in the file token/program-2022/src/extension/confidential_transfer/verify_proof.rs from the solana-program-library
The error message is:
expected `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`

Has anyone else faced this issue? How can I resolve this error?

This problem is a result of SPL crates allowing multiple incompatible versions of Solana dependencies, and not related to Solana 1.18.17 or Anchor 0.30.1 specifically.
To fix this problem, you can downgrade Solana v2 dependencies by manually editing your lock file or simply running:
cargo update -p solana-zk-token-sdk@2.0.0 --precise 1.18.17

Related GitHub issues: coral-xyz/anchor#3044, solana-labs/solana-program-library#6897
